# How do I lock the values (with a button) 10 seconds before in a loop?

Tags: arduino, sensors

I've been creating a project that involves the Mq-3 sensor. When the sensor gets an increase of value of 51%, then the RedLED will blink. As for this, I have created used a formula based on ratios and the data I collected from respondents.

```cpp
sensorVal=analogRead(sensorPin);  //read SensorPin
sensorCalc51=(322./150.)*sensorVal; //This is the 51% value that the arduino makes that is dependent on the sensorVal
```

```cpp
if (sensorVal >= sensorCalc51) {           //the condition involves both the sensorVal and sensorCalc51
    for (int i=0; i<=20; i=i+1) {       
        analogWrite(redPin,255);
        delay (500);
        analogWrite(redPin,000);
        delay (500);
    }
```

As you can see in the code, the condition will NEVER be true as the formula always makes the `sensorCalc51` higher than the `sensorVal`.
I need to make the `sensorCalc51` lock it's latest value through a button so that it
won't go higher when the person breathes on the sensor, and it actually makes the condition TRUE.

Comment: Keep a history of read sensor values.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your sensorCalc51 in an if statement and store the value in either a global or a static local:

```
void test() {
  static float sensorCalc51 = 10000.0;  //to insure it doesn't fire before it's set properly
  int sensorVal;

  sensorVal = analogRead(sensorPin); //read SensorPin

  // now check if the button is pressed.  If so update sensorCalc51
  // the digitalRead will be HIGH or LOW when switch is pressed
  // depending on the type of switch
  if (digitalRead(mySwitch)) {
    sensorCalc51 = (322. / 150.) * sensorVal;
  }

  if (sensorVal >= sensorCalc51) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i = i + 1) {
      analogWrite(redPin, 255);
      delay (500);
      analogWrite(redPin, 000);
      delay (500);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare engineeringValue

```
float engineeringValue = 0.0;
```

…

```
sensorVal=analogRead(sensorPin);  //read SensorPin
engineeringValue = Scale(sensorVal, 0.0, 100.0);

if(engineeringValue >= 51.0){
  for (int i=0; i<=20; i=i+1) {       
    analogWrite(redPin,255);
    delay (500);
    analogWrite(redPin,000);
    delay (500);
  }
}
```

Implement Scale Function

```
float Scale(int inputValue, float minEU, float maxEU) {
  return ((float)inputValue / 1023.0) * (maxEU - minEU) + minEU; // Return scaling value
}
```

FYR,
Analog Input with Buttons
https://youtu.be/hbVITxOVdMU